# Adding Foreign Key Constraint While Using Composite Key Giving Me ERROR

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I am trying to create three tables however I am getting error as

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES personal_details(personID)
)'
```

The above error is for third table i.e. table `hobbies_person`.

I am creating tables as follow.

```
CREATE TABLE personal_details (
    personID   INT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName  varchar(30),
    middleName varchar(30),
    lastName   varchar(30),
    age        INT,
    aboutMe    varchar(500)
);

CREATE TABLE hobbies (
    hobbID    INT PRIMARY KEY,
    hobbName  varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE hobbies_person (
    personID INT,
    hobbID   INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (personID, hobbID),
    FOREIGN KEY personID REFERENCES personal_details(personID)
);
```

I also tried with

```
CREATE TABLE hobbies_person (
    personID INT,
    hobbID   INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (personID, hobbID),
    FOREIGN KEY personID REFERENCES personal_details(personID),
    FOREIGN KEY hobbID   REFERENCES hobbies(hobbID)
);
```

but still same error.

### [Link to check query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/417b4)

Any idea how to tackle this?

### NOTE

In table `hobbies_person` I am using **composite primary key** as `PRIMARY KEY (personID, hobbID),`

Comment: Why do you define hbbID as unique if it's part of the primary key? Doesn't make sense

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Thanks for catching that... I removed that.. still same error...

Comment: Remove the "hobbID   INT UNIQUE KEY," to just
hobbID   INT , and then declare it along with person_id as primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `()` around your foreign key

```
FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES personal_details(personID)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to enclose the column `personID` in brackets for the FK definition:

```
CREATE TABLE hobbies_person (
    personID INT NOT NULL,
    hobbID   INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (personID, hobbID),
    FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES personal_details(personID)
);
```